# Air from powerful ceiling fan keeps rocking my laptop display 24*7

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure

air from powerful ceiling fan keeps rocking my laptop screen/monitor . I work in a small room with a ceiling fan above me. I noticed that the monitor/screen part of my laptop is shaking continously.(**Only lightly, but enough to be easily noticed**). This goes on 24*7 cos I work at home.

I am worried that if the delicate electronics inside the monitor are subjected to constant (light)shaking, my screen won't last long.

**I guess I am looking for someone to tell me slight screen shaking is okay,even if it's 24*7, and that my (cheap squeaky model!) laptop is sturdy enough to take it.**

Or should I do something about it?

Comment: put something sturdy behind your screen. but maybe your screen is just happy  and shaking its boot y

Comment: Light shaking of the screen is completely ok. I have been using my laptop like this for the past 4-5 years. I live in a hot and humid climate so the fans are always on at full speed during the summer. And just like yours mine is also a low end laptop. I have seen these happen even on expensive high end models also, so there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: But continuously watching a shaking screen could unhinge the viewer. Seriously, for your vision's sake, just prop something against the lid (or cobble up a support using a dowel with suction cups at both ends to hold to the lid and to rest on the desk).

Answer (score 0):

Your monitor should be fine.  There are no loose or mechanical parts that would break.  If you are comfortable opening up your laptop, you *might* be able to tighten the screws that hold the lid up to prevent it from shaking.